# Non-linear fitting using scipy.optimize.curvefit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit data using an exponential model:

```
def f(x, F_0, t0, tau):
    return F_0 * np.exp (-(x-t0)/tau)
```

I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` like this:

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f,t,y,maxfev=1000)
```

In theory that should be it, `popt` should give the values of `F_0`, `t0` and `tau` right? Well it gives me `[1,1,1]` and `pcov=inf`. What's going on?

The data I'm running this on is:

```
t = array([ 6.0989933 ,  6.13041162,  6.16183043,  6.19324923,  6.22466803, 6.25608683,  6.28750563,  6.31892443,  6.35034323,  6.38176203, 6.41318083,  6.44459963,  6.47601843,  6.50743675,  6.53885555, 6.57027435,  6.60169315,  6.63311195,  6.66453075,  6.69594955, 6.72736835,  6.75878716,  6.79020596,  6.82162476,  6.85304356, 6.88446236,  6.91588116,  6.94729996,  6.97871828,  7.01013708, 7.04155588,  7.07297468,  7.10439348,  7.13581228,  7.16723108, 7.19864988,  7.23006868,  7.26148748,  7.29290581,  7.32432461, 7.35574341,  7.38716221,  7.41858101,  7.44999981], dtype=np.float32)
y = array([  2.70034180e+03,   2.31075024e+03,   1.87097400e+03, 1.37248645e+03,   1.12983032e+03,   1.10378296e+03, 8.75943909e+02,   6.74242004e+02,   6.01329895e+02, 5.63800049e+02,   4.25704498e+02,   4.04536774e+02, 2.78763947e+02,   2.24465073e+02,   1.85565216e+02, 2.08205307e+02,   1.77108429e+02,   1.38598465e+02, 1.22449684e+02,   9.47472382e+01,   8.18683701e+01, 5.92218361e+01,   5.29379654e+01,   4.54894447e+01, 3.65242805e+01,   2.95051060e+01,   2.47274208e+01, 2.26564598e+01,   1.64215832e+01,   1.41874876e+01, 1.23035212e+01,   1.25391512e+01,   8.86111355e+00, 7.04269171e+00,   6.07329178e+00,   4.73968601e+00, 4.60453558e+00,   3.97630429e+00,   3.36820292e+00, 2.52790380e+00,   2.28720117e+00,   2.09139872e+00, 1.46813798e+00,   1.18916214e+00], dtype=np.float32)
```

I tried adding initial values close to the real values,

```
x0 = np.array([2500,6,0.15])
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f,t,y,x0,maxfev=1000)`
```

`popt` now gives me the values of `x0`.

Comment: If you read a bit up on how curve fitting algorithms work, you'll see you often need to help the algorithm a bit. Have you already tried passing an initial guess to `curve_fit`? Also, would your model function actually properly describe the data?

Comment: Yes I've tried adding the initial values

x0=np.array([2500,6,0.15])
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f,t,y,x0,maxfev=1000)

That gives me popt = [2500,6,0.15]

The real values should be somewhere around 2700.34, 6.09899 and 0.1707

Comment: Okay, show us then. Please update your question with that info and add your dataset. You won't get better help otherwise.

Comment: I added the data too

Comment: I get a decent fit (`0.60070708,  7.50371455,  0.16713689`) without even passing an initial guess. Is this the `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize`? Please add your scipy version then and consider reinstalling scipy if you also can't fit simple linear curves.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I use scipy.optimize, I don't know how to check my scipy version, but if that's the only issue then that's fine, can you post the code that gave you that fit?

Comment: `popt,pcov = curve_fit(f,t,y,maxfev=1000)` <- exactly what you have and using the variables you showed, like I said. Also, for your reference: `print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: Note that an exponential model is sensitive. Do you see how far your initial guess is different from what scipy finds for me? You could solve the sensitivity issue by calling the logarithm on your data, which makes it linear and thus far easier to do curve fitting against.

Answer (score 0):

I get:

```
F_0 =  6.7311012141178690E+00
t0 =  7.0998469795908647E+00
tau =  1.6713682175557676E-01
```

See attached graph.

```
Degrees of freedom (error): 41
Degrees of freedom (regression): 2
Chi-squared: 72831.3559855
R-squared: 0.995880600583
R-squared adjusted: 0.99567965427
Model F-statistic: 4955.95358568
Model F-statistic p-value: 1.11022302463e-16
Model log-likelihood: -225.490964337
AIC: 10.3859529244
BIC: 10.5076022176
Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): 40.6848631628

F_0 = 6.7311012141178690E+00
       std err: 1.09504E+14
       t-stat: 6.43238E-07
       p-stat: 9.99999E-01
       95% confidence intervals: [-2.11333E+07, 2.11333E+07]

t0 = 7.0998469795908647E+00
       std err: 6.75151E+10
       t-stat: 2.73243E-05
       p-stat: 9.99978E-01
       95% confidence intervals: [-5.24744E+05, 5.24758E+05]

tau = 1.6713682175557676E-01
       std err: 1.10988E-05
       t-stat: 5.01689E+01
       p-stat: 0.00000E+00
       95% confidence intervals: [1.60409E-01, 1.73865E-01]

Coefficient Covariance Matrix
[  6.16444921e+10  -1.53066514e+09   9.05030951e+00]
[ -1.53066514e+09   3.80072201e+07  -2.24723915e-01]
[  9.05030951e+00  -2.24723915e-01   6.24798951e-09]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I would like to point out that according to the parameter confidence intervals I posted above, F_0 and t0 might have a very wide range of possible values - but not tau.  The confidence intervals on the fitted value of tau are fairly tight, meaning there is a high confidence in the fitted values we both received for tau.